# Not able to read Services of BLE sensor from Nexus 5x with android 7

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-7.0-nougat

Recently i updated my nexus from Android 6 to Android 7.

- In Android 6 all BLE related Task was working. But in Android 7 it is not working.
- some time connection is happening and after sometime it will disconnect immediately.

Please give some suggestions for resolve this issue.

Comment: Please provide some logs, such as logcat or Bluetooth hci snoop log.

Comment: Also show how you use the ble apis. For example do you use autoConnect, do you usually close GATT objects or rather reconnect with the same GATT objects etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is an official issue from Google. I refer to [this topic](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/rz3BGwI-BDA).

EDIT: The discussed solution for this problem is to flash a factory image. More information and instruction can be found over [here](https://developers.google.com/android/images).

Comment: with latest update from google, this is working fine for me.

Comment: Google nexus 7.1.1 release I am able to pair. But in Moto G4 ,Moto g4+ , one plus 3T having same issue , not yet fixed in latest 7.0 release.